# Postgresql count divided by count

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, count, sum

I am trying to get a sale success rate by month in the city if Miami. The variables I have are: call id, date of the call, city, and the status of the call (sale or no sale). I have 0 in the success rate column, is it a syntax or data type error? The code is written using PostgreSQL.

```
select date_trunc('month', call_date)::DATE as date,
       count(c.id) FILTER (WHERE c.status='sale') as success_cnt,
       count(c.id) as all_cnt,
       sum((count(c.id) FILTER (WHERE c.status='sale)'))/count(c.id)) over() as success_rate
       from user.call as c
where city='Miami')
group by 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused where the window functions come in.  For the success rate, you can use:

```
select date_trunc('month', call_date)::date as date,
       count(*) FILTER (where c.status = 'sale') as success_cnt,
       count(*) as all_cnt,
       avg( (c.status = 'sale')::int ) as success_rate
from user.call c
where city = 'Miami'
group by 1;
```

Comment: Hi, can you please explain why you apply an average function on a string, or how this string can be casted to an integer in this case?

Comment: The string is being compared to a value, producing a boolean. Then that boolean is being cast to integer (1 = true, 0 = false). Taking the average of those integers yields success rate.

Comment: I added a condition within the average function and now it shows ERROR: syntax error at or near "filter" This is what I added `avg((c.status = 'sale' filter ( where profession in ('student', 'unemployed')))::int)`

Comment: Try `avg( (c.status = 'sale')::int ) FILTER (WHERE profession IN ('student', 'unemployed'))`

Answer (score 1):

`count()` returns an integer, and when you divide integers you get an integer result, with the remainder thrown away.  If you want a fractional result, you need to cast one of the inputs to a fractional type before dividing.